# Why am I getting Server Error in '/' Application?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have been trying to fix this on my site but I am having no luck and every page I have found with its fix tells to set customErrors mode="Off" and I have already done that. This server error only occurs on one page, but the one page is the page where a majority of the sites functionality resides.

I am running .Net 4.0, and I have just recently published this same site in the same way with no problems at all. There has been no changes to my web.config file.

Here is a little code sample from my web.config where I have the customErrors set to off

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

if anyone can provide some helpful insight, it will be greatly appreciated, if there is more code needed to solve this I will provided what is requested. Thank you

Comment: allow users="?" it should not be equal to allow  users= "*" or deny users="?" if i'm not wrong ?

Comment: If settings customErrors Off isnt' giving you more info then it's likely a problem in your web.config.  Trim that down considerably (including getting rid of that security stuff) and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a days worth of looking for the answer it has been found. Someone made a change to one of the database names without informing me. So my problem was I had a wrong name of a database nothing else was wrong.

Thank you all